# Help in double precision addition

Tags: javascript, addition, double-precision

I was testing some of my code, in javascript I added .1+.2 and it gives me .30000000000000004 instead of .3 . I don't understand this.
But when I added .1+.3 it gives me .4. I googled it and find its something about Double Precision addition. But I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the obligatory link: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Basically, there are many base 10 numbers that cannot be exactly represented in the floating point format used by most computers, so you'll get issues like the ones you highlight.

Comment: :) I think I've read 20% of it a hundred times...one day I'll be able to stay awake.

Comment: its a big article, can you tell me the essence if you have read it.

Comment: @vaibhav: I thought I had. Some numbers can't be written in a fixed number of decimal places (e.g. 1/3), in base 10. In base 2 (which is how it's stored in the computer) floating point format, there are also numbers that can't be written (or stored) in a fixed number of decimal places..and they aren't always the same as the ones in base 10. So you can't help but have these sorts of errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't stay awake for *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*, try instead the javascript-specific [Rounding in JavaScript](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-round.htm#RiJ).

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers have a finite amount of precision, as the number is stored in a finite number of bits.

The number you are trying to store can't be stored accurately, so an approximation is used.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) .