# JavaScript number addition confusion

Tags: javascript

I am a little bit confused about how JavaScript acts when adding numbers to big numbers.
I thought the numbers are too big, but it seems like this is not the case.
Broken down the problem to this additions (Google Chrome Dev Console):

[image]

What is the reason for this behaviour and how to avoid it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help in double precision addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093534/help-in-double-precision-addition)

Comment: "*I thought the numbers are too big, but it seems like this is not the case.*' why do you think it's not the case when you observe a problem that occurs with integers that are too big?

Comment: @LMD not related to floating point arithmetic. It's a separate issue which concerns integers.

Comment: See also [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER); your numbers exceed it.

Comment: @VLAZ very much related to floating point arithmetic; see e.g. [the JS Number type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). JS only knows doubles. Even if you use doubles as integers, you're still using doubles (mantissa-exponent) so you get the same precision issues, except the exponent is positive, not negative.

Comment: @LMD so, you think this is a rounding error with fractions?

Comment: @VLAZ yes. Basically, the resulting number requires one (mantissa) bit too much, so you lose one bit of integer precision (hence why their addition yields the closest multiple of two).

Comment: You can fix this by using [the BigInt datatype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) in relatively modern browsers

Comment: 1e16+1..toFixed(0)  //10000000000000001

Comment: @WillBlack umm, `<number> + <string>` results in *string concatenation*.